# Display message to user on expired session when using wicket-auth-roles

Tags: session, wicket, session-timeout, wicket-1.6

Hi I have been unable to solve the following problem in Wicket 6.*:

In our webapp we are using wicket-auth-roles to manage authentication/authorization. When session expires, user should be redirected to a page set by `getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(SomePage.class)` on his next action. However, if the user tries to access a page which doesn't allow guests, he is redirected to a login page skipping the PageExpiredPage altogether.

My question is - how can I display "Session has expired." message to the user?

Among other things, I have tried `session.info("message")` during `onInvalidate` phase of session's lifecycle, however the feedback message is then rendered on the first page after login (not on the login page).

Thank you for your anwsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [bernie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030527/bernie) put me on the right path, I eventually figured out a solution to the problem:

First it is required to override `RequestCycleListener`:

```
public class SessionExpiredListener extends AbstractRequestCycleListener {
  public void onRequestHandlerResolved(RequestCycle cycle, IRequestHandler handler) {
    if (handler instanceof IPageRequestHandler) {
        IPageRequestHandler pageHandler = (IPageRequestHandler) handler;

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) cycle.getRequest().getContainerRequest();

        //check whether the requested session has expired
        boolean expired = request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid();

        //check whether the requested page can be instantiated with the current session
        boolean authorized = Session.get().getAuthorizationStrategy().isInstantiationAuthorized(pageHandler.getPageClass());

        if (expired && !authorized) {
            throw new PageExpiredException("Session has expired!");
        }

    }
    super.onRequestHandlerResolved(cycle, handler);
  }
}
```

Check for `authorized` prevents the session-expired message from displaying on log-out or when accessing unprotected pages.

Finally, you must register your listener and `PageRequestHandlerTracker` in your `WebApplication`:

```
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new SessionExpiredListener());
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new PageRequestHandlerTracker());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `RequestCycleListener` to record when a `PageExpiredException` is thrown.

```
public class ExceptionMapperListener extends AbstractRequestCycleListener {

    @Override
    public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof PageExpiredException) {
            // Record in session or request cycle
            // OR
            // Create a RenderPageRequestHandler yourself and add a page parameter
            // See DefaultExceptionMapper#internalMap(Exception)
        }
        return null;
    }
}

// In Application#init():
getRequestCycleListeners().add(new ExceptionMapperListener());
```

## ORINAL ANSWER

(kept because it could still help...)

I haven't tried it myself since I don't use wicket-auth-roles, but try overriding the method `AuthenticatedWebApplication#restartResponseAtSignInPage()` with something like this:

```
if (isSessionExpired()) {
    PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
    params.add("showSessionExpired", true);
    throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(getSignInPageClass(), params);
} else {
    throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(getSignInPageClass());
}
```

And then in the SignInPageClass, display the desired message if the `showSessionExpired` page parameter is present.

I'm not sure how you implement `isSessionExpired()`, but you seem to have that part already covered.

### OR

Depending on how you implemented `isSessionExpired()`, maybe you could do the following in your SignInPageClass:

```
if (sessionExpired()) {
    session.info("message")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `isSessionExpired()` is exactly the part where I'm stuck. I'm unable to tell whether the current session is just _new_ or _new after the previous one expired_ inside  `AuthenticatedWebApplication` class.

Comment: Your update set me on the right path, I think. I need to implement `onBeginRequest(RequestCycle cycle)` of the `RequestCycleListener`, where I can check for the requested session validity. Only issue I still need to figure is how to distinguish expired session from intentionally invalidated one (e.g. when user logs out). Will provide more information after I solve it.